# Get all href values from a string which is filled with HTML code from a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

Solved :)

```js
  var test = $('textarea[name=extract]').val();
    var hh =  $.parseHTML(test) ;


    $.each($(test).find('.tile__link'),function(i,b){
        var reff = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.links').append("link/" +reff + "<br><br>");
    })
```

I have HTML code copied from an website. And I want all `href` values with the class `.tile_link` in a String.

I did not find an solution, how I can get the value of `href` with the class `.tile_link` without the divs and text just the link?

Here's an example:

```js
var test = $('textarea[name=extract]').val();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="extract">
      <span class="txt-raise">8min</span>
    </div></div>
        <div class="js-hunq-badge fit-tr pr-- pt--"></div>


        <div class="tile__footprint">
        </div>

      </a>
    </div><div class="tile grid-tile tile--bordered">  <a href="#/profile//grid" class="tile__link">

        <div role="image" aria-label="HSHBerl" style="background-image:url()" class="tile__image"></div>

        <div class="bg-raise tile__info">

          <div class="info info--middle txt-raise">

            <div class="txt-truncate layout-item--consume">
                <div class="typo-small lh-heading txt-truncate">
                  8&nbsp;km <span class="icon icon-small icon-gps-needle icon-badge"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="lh-heading txt-truncate">
                  <div class="info__main-data">
                    <div class="info__username">

                    </div>
                    <div class="js-romeo-badge"></div>

                    <div class="info__icon-set">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>

        <div class="tile__onlinestate js-online-state"><div>


        <span class="icon icon-online-status ui-status--online icon-raise" title="Online"></span>
</textarea>
```

But I don't know how to extract it to get only the values of `href`.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I think this would work: $(".tile_link").text().  If you want the text from all of them, you'll use the same selector, but loop through and get the .text() from each of them.

Comment: I've done research, otherwise I would not ask. Well, my exmaples did not work at all, so why should I post not working code?

Comment: Why post non-working code? So that we can see that you did the research, and so that we can help you, not just write code for you. Some of us get paid for writing code for others; seems kind of disrespectful to expect people to do it for free...

Comment: I've added stuff which should make it easier to understand. And I don't want that someone codes stuff for me, I want help.

Comment: I've edited your code into a snippet which I think demonstrates the issue. I suggest reviewing [the documentation for jQuery, specifically the `parseHTML` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parseHTML/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do someting like this:

```
$(".tile_link").attr('href');
```

If you have more than one element with that class, you can do forEach or map.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Example:

```
$('.tile_link').map(function (element) { return $(this).attr('href'); });
```